# How to use pandas.qcut to make deciles out of values in a column

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am currently trying to manipulate some data into 10 quantiles.

The dataframe I have loaded has a column A, B, and C

My current code can break them into 10 equal size groups but what I am trying to achieve is based off of the actual number within the rows. So I want to break it into 10 deciles of equal sum of the value in column C. This will certainly mean that the deciles will have a different amount of entries per bucket. Is this possible through pd.qcut? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Current code is as follows:

```
user_df['decile'] = pd.qcut(user_df['C'].rank(method='first').values, 10, duplicates='drop').codes + 1 
user_df.groupby('decile')
```

How can I sort by the actual values in column C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
```

Then we can build a strictly monotonic series based on column `'C'` with

```
c = df.C.values
c -= c.min()
c = c.cumsum()
```

Then establish the boundaries of our buckets

```
cuts = np.arange(11) * c[-1] / 10
```

Finally assign a new column

```
df['decile'] = cuts.searchsorted(c)
# equivalent but slower
# df['decile'] = pd.cut(c, cuts, labels=range(1, 11))
```

---

It's not perfect as I built buckets in whatever order they appeared

```
df.groupby('decile').C.sum()

decile
1     4.060410
2     3.728364
3     4.417033
4     4.119732
5     4.070618
6     4.450897
7     3.981932
8     4.504357
9     3.733634
10    4.738445
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

However, over `1000` rows

```
df.groupby('decile').C.sum()

decile
1     48.481552
2     49.718306
3     49.108860
4     49.443570
5     49.205949
6     49.017016
7     48.973904
8     49.427361
9     49.152014
10    49.436423
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Comment: this did the trick! thank you!!! not familar with cumsum, will have to look into this.